# Template Metaprogramming w/Type Traits: Why does the first code compile and the second doesn't?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, type-traits

I've got two sets of code, the first of which compiles and behaves as expected, but is [appearing to be] needlessly verbose:

```
template<point_type type, typename T>
struct point2d_base {
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, T> x, y;
    template<point_type t2 = type>
    point2d_base(std::enable_if_t<t2 == point_type::generic, T> x = 0, T y = 0) :
        x(x), y(y) {}
    template<point_type t2 = type>
    explicit point2d_base(std::enable_if_t<t2 != point_type::generic, T> x = 0, T y = 0) :
        x(x), y(y) {}
/*Some unrelated code*/
};
```

This is the code I'd rather write, but I get many, many compile errors if I do it like this:

```
template<point_type type, typename T>
struct point2d_base {
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, T> x, y;
    point2d_base(std::enable_if_t<type == point_type::generic, T> x = 0, T y = 0) :
        x(x), y(y) {}
    explicit point2d_base(std::enable_if_t<type != point_type::generic, T> x = 0, T y = 0) :
        x(x), y(y) {}
/*Some unrelated code*/
};
```

For reference sake, `point_type` is an "Enum Class" that contains three values: `generic`, `corner`, `center`.

My question is: Why does the first code compile, and the second doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't rely on your template class parameters for using `std::enable_if`.
If you want to use `std::enable_if` with a function, you have to make that function a template function.
It's because when you class template is instantiated all member function of that class instantiate too. You need a template member function to conditionally enable that function or not.
(It's my guess and I think is correct)

Comment: Is there a correct version of the code that is closer to what I've written in the second example, where I don't need to redeclare the `type` variable as something else?

Comment: If you want to use `std::enable_if` I don't think so. The other option based on your requirements can be Template specialization.